# visual studio code not recognizing html files

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

VS code has suddenly stopped recognizing html files (the file icon is the default one for files with no extension)

all other file extensions work just fine

[image: all other file extensions work just fine]

except for html

[image: except for html]

the tags still work but it won't autocomplete

Comment: If you type `@builtin html` in the search box of the extensions pane, what do you get? And, have you customised `files.associations`?

Comment: Same for me, no 'files.associations' or exclusions in the settings and also no HTML files in the tree nav. Even the "open file" picker is not showing them. Adding the *.html association did not work...

Answer (score 21):

Adding this to file extensions  worked for me:

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.html": "html"  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, for this problem the solution was to manually add `*.html` to `files.associations`, in user settings. Its unlogical but it seems that somehow the extension wasn't associated to the type of file. Now everything works perfectly...

Answer (score 6):

Go to the settings (In mac it is **Code -- > Preferences --> Settings**)

1. In the search bar search for **Association**.
2. In Files:Associations click on **Add items**.
3. update  key = *.html & Value = html

Below is the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but none of the other solutions worked for me!

**You can try this:**

Go to the path where the "settings.json" file exits, for my case the path is:
C:> Users> User123 > AppData > Roaming > Code > User > settings.json

Now, paste the code in the file:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
        "html": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"",
    }
```

Now search for the `"files.associations"` section in your settings.json file:
[As an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxUEF.png)

Now if you have the `"files.associations"` section then just add the line there:

```
"*html": "html"
```

(don't forget to write a comma after a line if there are more lines in it)

or if you don't have a `"files.associations"` section, then copy paste the code there:

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.rmd": "markdown",
        "*html": "html"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows 10 a few minutes ago:
Yeah, from the solutions above I did this but still had some errors:

**File -- > Preferences --> Settings**

In the search bar search for **Files: Association**.

In Files:Associations click on **Add item** button.

update Item = ***.html** & Value = **HTML**
As shown below:
[image]

When I saved, I got this error

> `Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.`

The problem is that **terminal.integrated.shellArgs settings have been deprecated.**

One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199111/visual-studio-code-cmd-error-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabl/67420296#67420296) will help:

Answer (score 0):

So I just had this problem and I figured it out the problem was from an extension that I installed which is the pyscript extension I disabled it and everything started to work again!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have `pyscript extension` installed, disable it. It has conflicts with html files I guess.

Or if you don't want to disable it just `ctrl+shift+p` then `change language mode`. Select configure file association for html.

This applies for any extension not just pyscript. For me it was pyscript